# Switch Button Not Working From API Handling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem. I made switch button based on API. Just change "on"/"off" in my view. But When I clicked button "off", my button changed to "on" but when i clicked "on" its not working. And then after I clicked , my button can't clicked again. So weird. Any solution for me ? I need help.

**Controller :**

This controller to showing `isactive` API is on or off. And showing based `isactive`

```
$scope.result[item._id] =   {
     item : item,
     active : item.active,
     btn_label : item.active === 0 ? "On" : "Off"
};
```

So, I put `btn_label` inside **view** like this :

```
<tbody ng-repeat="data in result">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{ startnumber + $index + 1 }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ data.item._id }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ data.item.title }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ data.item.category.label }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ data.item.user.name }}
                        </td>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="FiturThread(data.item)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> {{ data.btn_label }}</button>
</tbody>
```

I think , just change **btn_label** in $scope **FiturThread** but not working

```
$scope.FiturThread = function(data) {

        if(data.btn_label === 0){
            data.btn_label = "Off";
        }else{
            data.btn_label = "On";
        }
};
```

Please help me or give me solution , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data.btn_label` is never equals to zero so you never get "on" label.
Maybe you dissmissed with `active` property?

I would suggest you to use boolean active property like this:

```
...
active: item.active,
btn_label : item.active ? "On" : "Off"
...

$scope.FiturThread = function(data) {
    data.active = !data.active;
    data.btn_label = data.active ? "On" : "Off"
};
```

It's much more compact and clear.

And also you should send to controller method data : `ng-click="FiturThread(data)"`

Comment: Yes, i try to change condition with data.active === 0 but nothing gonna happen . The console is correct but my button not switched

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
$scope.FiturThread = function(data) {

        if(data.btn_label === 'On'){
            data.btn_label = "Off";
        }else{
            data.btn_label = "On";
        }
};
```